# Was Jesus perfect his entire life? - Isaiah 7

Tags: life-of-jesus, good-and-evil, isaiah, perfection

Was Jesus perfect his entire life? This passage seems to suggest otherwise. I've never had a good answer to this question when referring to this passage.

> Again the Lord spoke to Ahaz, “Ask a sign of the Lord your God; let it
>   be deep as Sheol or high as heaven.” But Ahaz said, “I will not ask,
>   and I will not put the Lord to the test.” And he said, “Hear then, O
>   house of David! Is it too little for you to weary men, that you weary
>   my God also? Therefore the Lord himself will give you a sign. **Behold,
>   the virgin shall conceive and bear a son, and shall call his name
>   Immanuel. He shall eat curds and honey when he knows how to refuse the
>   evil and choose the good. For before the boy knows how to refuse the
>   evil and choose the good, the land whose two kings you dread will be
>   deserted.** The Lord will bring upon you and upon your people and upon
>   your father's house such days as have not come since the day that
>   Ephraim departed from Judah—the king of Assyria.”
>   ~ Isaiah 7:10-17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the passage you mention it never says Jesus sinned or did evil.  We can find the answer to that question in Hebrews 4:14-15

> Seeing then that we have a great High Priest who has passed through
>   the heavens, Jesus the Son of God, let us hold fast our confession. 
>   For we do not have a High Priest who cannot sympathize with our
>   weaknesses, but was in all points tempted as we are, yet without sin.

More info here - http://www.amazingfacts.org/media-library/book/e/18/t/christs-human-nature.aspx

Comment: Just because he was always good doesn't mean he was always _perfect_, though I don't mean _perfect_ in the moral sense, I mean _perfect_ in the sense of completeness. He was born a child. A child is an "incomplete" man. Incompleteness is an imperfection.  The Father is complete, and perfect in all ways. A child will _learn_ and _grow_ and become a man. The scriptures tell us that Jesus _learned_ obedience, _was made_ perfect, and and _was raised_ to the highest places. This is why he said "The Father is greater than I," he was not yet finished: he still needed to become the Lamb who was slain.

Answer (score 5):

This is the NIV translation:

> He will be eating curds and honey when he knows enough to reject the wrong and choose the right

Children are not aware of good or evil until they reach a certain age, "[age of accountability](http://www.gotquestions.org/age-of-accountability.html)", and understanding. One cannot choose to do good or evil until one is aware of what good and evil are and the differences between them, and choose for themselves. That seems to be what this verse is implying. Bible passages would tell us that *we* are sinful even at birth ([Psalm 51:5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm%2051:5&version=NIV)), but as @HelloWorld said, this verse does not necessarily say that Jesus was sinful before that time.

> Before I was born the Lord called me
>   Isaiah 49:1

Answer (score 3):

There are two fulfillments of this passage:

Firstly, an imminent and very literal fulfillment: the sign is that a young woman (one meaning of the Hebrew word 'almah') will conceive and have a child, and by the time they are 12 - 13 (that's when Judaism of that time would consider them to 'know right from wrong'), the lands of the two kings Ahaz fears, Israel and Aram/Syria will be  laid waste (which is what actually happened).

The second fulfillment is a 'remez' (or hint) of the first. It takes place in a different time (about 700 years later) and this time the sign is that a virgin (the other meaning of 'almah') will give birth to a son. He will be 'God with us' but not literally called by that name. This use of prophecies with an imminent context and then with a slightly different and later context was well known in Hebrew prophecy and hence the use of the Hebrew term 'remez'.

Matthew was an educated man and a learned scholar in Jewish Law (almost the same for Jews of that time) and he would have understood this use of prophecy and 'remez'. He does something similar with Hosea 11:1 (which is historic) and makes it a prophecy which he quotes in Matthew 2:15 ('out of Egypt I called my son'). Here again is 'remez' in action. There is another similar idea in Matthew 2:18:

> A voice is heard in Ramah,
>       weeping and great mourning,
>   Rachel weeping for her children
>       and refusing to be comforted,
>       because they are no more.
>   (quoting Jeremiah 31:15)

Bearing all this in mind the second later prophecy (the 'remez' one) does not have to fit the details exactly literally like the earlier one. Therefore it doesn't imply that Jesus was not perfect his entire life. This also resolves the 'almah' dispute by considering its use to have been deliberately ambiguous.

Comment: I'm not aware of the term 'remez', but the idea of multiple fulfilments of prophecy is an important one in Christianity too.

Comment: Though interesting and relevant to one part of the prophecy quoted in the question, this does not actually address or answer the question of whether Jesus was perfect his entire life.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that the passage you quoted suggests 'the boy' Jesus sinned.  It talks about Him being in a state which is before He knows how to refuse the evil and choose the good, but noone in such a state could be said to have sinned, since sin is a choice.  If someone doesn't know how to refuse the evil and choose the good, it means they are too young to be able to make choices and so too young to sin, rather than that they are constantly doing evil because they don't know how to refuse it, as you seem to have read it.

Comment: "sin is a choice" -- do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: Sin is a position we're all born into.  It's our nature being born of the seed of Adam where like produces like.  Jesus was not born of the seed of Adam.  Gen 3:15.

Comment: My reading of the scriptures includes sin being a choice.  Whilst I believe that it's impossible to choose the good without the grace and love of God constraining us to do so, it is still a choice: one which God elects certain people to choose, by His grace. There is more than one reference I could give to support this reading. I choose one from the passage quoted in this question: 'He shall eat curds and honey when he knows how to refuse the evil and choose the good. For before the boy knows how to refuse the evil and choose the good, the land whose two kings you dread will be deserted.'

Comment: It's seems clear to me from this that good is something we can choose. By definition a choice must be between a number of different options. If we have only one option, we have no choice. Thus for us to be able to 'choose the good', there must be at least one other thing we can choose: evil, which is to sin. Thus, sin is a choice: a bad choice. I agree that we were all born (the first time) in sin and this was a result of Adam's bad choice.

Comment: However, until a child reaches the age when it knows how to refuse the evil and choose the good, it can't possibly have sinned. Romans 5.13 says '(For until the law sin was in the world, but sin is not imputed when there is no law.' A child which can't understand words yet cannot know any law. As such, no sin will be imputed. Furthermore, my reading of he Bible is that sin always involves someone disobeying a command of God. Whilst one person's disobedience can bring the wrath of God on others, the sin that incurs this wrath is always disobedience to a command of God by some person.

Comment: Today, when a child reaches the age at which it knows how to refuse the evil and choose the good, they can be born again and this happens when they are baptised in water by full immersion:  'In Him you were also circumcised with the circumcision made without hands, by putting off the body of the sins of the flesh, by the circumcision of Christ, buried with Him in baptism, in which you also were raised with Him through faith in the working of God, who raised Him from the dead. (Col 2.11-12).

Comment: Before they reach this point, although they are in sin, they haven't sinned themselves: the sin they are in is the sin they are born into by being of the corrupted seed of Adam. Once they reach the age of knowing how to refuse the evil and choose the good, if they hear the gospel and fail to be born again, this in will dominate them and they will choose evil. In fact, by rejecting the gospel, everything they do will be evil:

Comment: 'To the pure all things are pure, but to those who are defiled and unbelieving nothing is pure; but even their mind and conscience are defiled. They profess to know God, but in works they deny Him, being abominable, disobedient, and disqualified for every good work.' (Titus 1.15-16). If they haven't heard the gospel, they will be judged by how they respond to their conscience, but when God sees someone trying to be good, He sends someone to preach the gospel to them:

Comment: There was a certain man in Caesarea called Cornelius, a centurion of what was called the Italian Regiment, a devout man and one who feared God with all his household, who gave alms generously to the people, and prayed to God always. About the ninth hour of the day he saw clearly in a vision an angel of God coming in and saying to him, “Cornelius!” And when he observed him, he was afraid, and said, “What is it, lord?” So he said to him, “Your prayers and your alms have come up for a memorial before God. Now send men to Joppa, and send for Simon whose surname is Peter.

Comment: He is lodging with Simon, a tanner, whose house is by the sea. He will tell you what you must do.” (Acts 10.1-6).  Then Peter opened his mouth and said: “In truth I perceive that God shows no partiality. But in every nation whoever fears Him and works righteousness is accepted by Him. (Acts 10.34-35). And we are witnesses of all things which He did both in the land of the Jews and in Jerusalem, whom they killed by hanging on a tree. (Acts 10.39).

Comment: Him God raised up on the third day, and showed Him openly, not to all the people, but to witnesses chosen before by God, even to us who ate and drank with Him after He arose from the dead. And He commanded us to preach to the people, and to testify that it is He who was ordained by God to be Judge of the living and the dead. To Him all the prophets witness that, through His name, whoever believes in Him will receive remission of sins.” While Peter was still speaking these words, the Holy Spirit fell upon all those who heard the word. (Acts 10.40-44).

Comment: And those of the circumcision who believed were astonished, as many as came with Peter, because the gift of the Holy Spirit had been poured out on the Gentiles also. For they heard them speak with tongues and magnify God. Then Peter answered, “Can anyone forbid water, that these should not be baptized who have received the Holy Spirit just as we have?” And he commanded them to be baptized in the name of the Lord. (Act 10.45-48).

Answer (score 0):

In Hebrews 2:10-11, it says:

> In bringing many sons and daughters to glory, it was fitting that God,
>   for whom and through whom everything exists, should make the pioneer
>   of their salvation perfect through what he suffered. Both the one who 
>   makes people holy and those who are made holy are of the same family. 
>   So Jesus is not ashamed to call them brothers and sisters.

The others who answered took up the question of sin and righteousness and the age of accountability. Perfection is more than just not sinning. The passage in Hebrews declares that there is a sense in which Jesus attained perfection through suffering, hence it was a process. The perfection he attained was his ability to relate to humanity through the shared suffering of life on earth, and supreme suffering of the Cross. His compassion and empathy was made perfect by showing his love and not rejecting the poor and miserable who flocked to him. Unlike Bill Clinton, he can say, "I feel your pain" and really mean it.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Isaiah 7 consider this…  The bible says that Jesus was made perfect, but being re-made in flesh, he had to go through the natural human steps to reaching His full potential…

***Hebrews 5:8 Though he were a Son, yet learned he obedience by the things which he suffered.***

The bible says that sin is a transgression of the law…

***1 John 3:4 Whosoever committeth sin transgresseth also the law: for sin is the transgression of the law.***

The question is, are all acts of disobedience considered sin (transgression of the law)?

Comment: Welcome! It's not clear to me what your answer is here. Was he perfect or not? This answer would also be stronger if you provided a source for this line of reasoning.